# Class.forName casts

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting

In Java, will using Class.forName in a cast result in the object being cast to a class or being cast to the cast found. As an example, if you did this

```
Object a;
String b = "testing";
a = (Class.forName("java.lang.Object")) b;
```

Would a be an instance of Class or an instance of Object?

Comment: I've answered the question you actually asked, but my suspicion is that you have an underlying, different question; questions like these usually result from an underlying problem that someone's trying to solve, but has gone down the wrong path. I recommend posting a (separate) question asking that underlying question, people can probably show you how to get there.

Comment: Neither: That code does not compile, and hence can't be executed ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Class.forName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) returns a [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance. I'm fairly certain your code as quoted doesn't compile, you're trying to use a function call as a cast.

---

**Update**: Just had a thought: If you're asking how to use a dynamically-loaded class in a cast, you basically can't. Casting is (mostly) a compile-time thing. Have the dynamically-loaded class implement an interface you can compile into your code and then cast to that, or if you can't do that, use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) to access the dynamically-loaded class' members.

Answer (score 11):

You can cast with the class object's `.cast` method:

```
Object a;
String b = "testing";
a = Class.forName("java.lang.Object").cast(b);
```

But you seem to have wrong ideas about casting - in Java, casting *does not change any object*, it just tells the compiler that the object is of some type, and on runtime, the VM will test if this is really the case (if the compiler can't already prove it). If you "cheated", the VM will throw an `ClassCastException` here (it will not convert your object).

(It works a bit different if primitive types are involved.)

The Class object's `cast` method is a generic variant of this same mechanism. Since it has the return type `T` (from `Class<T>`), this allows generic code to cast an unknown object to some class type, where this class object corresponds to a type variable.
This will not help you here - the return type of `Class.forName` is `Class<?>`, which means that its cast method can only return `Object`.

And anyway, casting to java.lang.Object has no effect (it will always succeed), other than hiding the to the compiler that the value has some specialized type. (This might matter if you have overloaded methods.)

Simply writing

```
Object a;
String b = "testing";
a = b;
```

has the same effect here.

Answer (score 3):

If it is required to cast an instance this is a way to do it

```
String className         = "YourClass";
Class someClass          = Class.forName( className );
Constructor constructor  = (Constructor) someClass.getConstructor();
Object someInstance      = constructor.newInstance();

// now you can cast as allways.
(YourClass) (someInstance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Class.forName always returns the **Class**.