# How can cast object of query dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

With the hibernate criteria I am getting unique result.

```
  Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(basepackagePath+this.castingClass);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ClassName", className));
  (this.castingClass)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

**Problem**: not able to cast criteria.uniqueResult()'s result.

**What I tried**:

1. I mentioned full package path to cast
2. Tried to get class with this.castingClass String but not happened

Please suggest how can I cast object dynamically with String which is holding name of object.

Comment: Given that you don't know the class at compile-time, what do you expect that to achieve? What do you expect to do with the cast version that you can't do without casting? You can't call any extra methods etc, because you don't know the type at compile-time.

Comment: You can use @Paŭlo Ebermann answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808130/class-forname-casts

Answer (score 0):

You could cast dynamically `criteria.uniqueResult()` result using the `cast`-Method.

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(basepackagePath+this.castingClass);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ClassName", className));
Class.forName(this.castingClass).cast(criteria.uniqueResult());
```