# How to type cast an object based on String passed

Tags: java, casting

Problem : I have multiple classes and I have received object of type "Object" in some method along with string which mentions the name of class to which that Object belongs. I need to typecast the Object that I received to one of the class type based on String.

Example :

```
public class Cat
{
  // Having Methods and Variables
}

public class Dog
{
  // Having Methods and Variables
}
```

Now following method in some other class will be called :

```
public void Method1(Object o, String s)
{
   Method2((Typecast based on value in s)o);  // s can be "Cat" or "Dog"

}
```

Method2 is overloaded i.e there are two types of it :

```
public void Method2(Dog g)
{

}

public void Method2(Cat c)
{

}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808130/class-forname-casts   `Method2(Class.forName(s).cast(o));`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Giving compilation error while enclosing inside the method.

Comment: I recommend to use factory method to return the objects based on string input.

Comment: @Sup19 I don't want to use switch or if else.

Comment: You are right.  the return type of Class.forName is Class<?>, which means that its cast method can only return Object, but it doesn't help you.  My mistake.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918550/cast-via-reflection-and-use-of-class-cast